# How to connect loose earth wire to hanging lamp

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, grounding, lamp

I bought a hanging lamp which came with two wires (L and N) connected to it, plus a loose earth wire with a "ring" attached to it (see photo below).
[image: Hanging lamp]

I would need to connect the lamp to the ceiling using this box (coming from the ceiling):
[image: Box]
The "white" wire is the earth wire (covered by some plastering).

I also have this hook (that will hold the lamp) that I need to screw in the ceiling:
[image: Hook]

My question is: where should I attach the loose earth wire to? Should I screw the "ring" of the loose earth wire to the hook of above, and then plug the rest of the wires? Something like this:
[image: Assembled]

Comment: I think that ring is suppose to go onto the shaft of the light and be tighten on, probably between two nuts.  This will connect the ground to the light.

Comment: …but the ground has nowhere to go in the rose. The earth connection is hopefully somewhere above that circular cover plate, sacrificing the convenient poke-through terminal strip if needs be.

Comment: could you link to the lamp's manual or at least a shopping item so we can see model number etc... I also suspect that ring is electrically connected to the lamp's shaft, which grounds the assembly through the metal chain etc... then the wire of the ring is connected to the ceiling pig tail